# Nginx+Passenger Error - libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found

Tags: nginx, passenger, ubuntu-18.04

#### System:

- Ubuntu: **18.04 LTS**
- Passenger: **5.3.1**
- `nginx` with `libnginx-mod-http-passenger`

`$ sudo nginx -t`

Returns:

```
PassengerLoggingAgent: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by PassengerLoggingAgent)
2018/06/04 02:28:40 [alert] 10411#0: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger logging agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)
```

```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install the required version 3 from the bionic repository if you don't depend on other software that already uses version 4:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3/bionic
```

This will ask you to remove *curl* itself, *libcurl4*, and dependend software. Consider carefully if you need those, before removing them.

You still can roll back by installing *libcurl4* and the removed software again.

Comment: It might work, but for me it tried to remove many installed programs (e.g VirtualBox)

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem:

`sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: This didn't change anything for me. Did you have the same error message?

Comment: Yep, the exact one. If you have this error while trying to install an R package you can reinstall RCurl with `install.packages('RCurl')`

Comment: Same here. Didn't do anything for me